# Kendo datasource OData not working when odata url is not localhost and web client host is localhost

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, odata

I have an OData service that returns the following json.

```
{
    "@odata.context":"http://testing.test.com/DataService/Data","value":[
    {"ID":1,"Description":"Test 1"}
    ,{"ID":2,"Description":"Test 2"}
    ,{"ID":3,"Description":"Test 3"}]
}
```

If both the odata service and the web page calling the odata service are on localhost then all works fine.
If the odata service is on a host like testing.test.com and the web page calling the odata service is on localhost then all does not work fine.
I can see in fiddler that the data is coming back to the client on localhost but the grid never displays the data.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://localhost/DataService/Data",
        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl,
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "value",
                    model: {
                        id: "ID"
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        columns: [
            { field: "ID", title: "ID", width: 70 }]
    });

});
</script>
```

The odata is hosted through ASP.NET web api odata not wcf.
The web client is hosted through ASP.NET web application general html.

I read somewhere that I might have to set crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" in the web.config but the seems to only be for WCF webHttpBinding. Yet I am using WEB API not WCF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it to work.
The ASP.NET Web API Odata service had to be modified to enable CORS (Cross-Origin Requests).

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api
http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/11-08-24/cross-domain_queries_to_odata_services_with_jquery